# Lexical: How to make nodes uneditable

Tags: reactjs, lexical, lexicaljs

I created my own node in Lexical and applied it some styles.

It uses the "token" mode: `node.setMode("token");`

I would like to disable displaying caret inside the node, just like on this image:

[image: Lexical editor showing custom node with a caret inside]

Ideally, when user clicks on the node, the caret would stay where it stays.

Here is a demo: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-move-caret-outside-of-token-forked-3t8h5c?file=/src/Editor.js)